# Redis - Why must always restart service? - MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk

Tags: php, windows, redis

I use Windows 10 as my server. I got a problem in Redis. Every month (or every certain times), I always got this error:

```
MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk
```

and after restart the Redis services, the problem solved, but after a certain time, the error appear again, and I must restart the service again. And after a certain time, the error appear again, restart the service again, and again, and again and again...

How can I solve this problem `permanently`?